# Scalaz: combine Writer and State (and/or Lens)

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I'm trying to combine Writer and State (through Lens). I'm pretty sure I need monad transformers, but I have difficulty figuring out how to use the T versions and how to build this properly.

Right now I have some models (simplified):

```
case class Schedule(due: LocalDate)
case class Task(title: String, schedule: Schedule)
```

Lenses defined for each field, `titleL`, `scheduleL` and `dueL`.

A type alias for my Writer `type Logger[A] = Writer[Vector[String], A]`

And some functions to modify my models:

```
def changeTitle(title: String): Task => Logger[Task] = { t: Task =>
  for {
    a <- titleL.set(t, title).point[Logger]
    _ <- ("Title changed to " + a.title).point[Vector].tell whenM (a.title != t.title)
  } yield a
}

def changeDue(date: LocalDate): Schedule => Logger[Schedule] = { s: Schedule =>
  for {
    a <- dueL.set(s, date).point[Logger]
    _ <- ("Due changed to " + a.due).point[Vector].tell whenM (a.due != s.due)
  } yield a
}
```

However now I'm unsure how to use the lens or state methods with that last function.

I'd like to be able to do something that would look kind of like this:

```
def reschedule(date: LocalDate): Task => Logger[Task] = { t: Task =>
  (for {
    a <- scheduleL %= reschedule(date)
    _ <- ("Reschedule: " + a.schedule).point[Vector].tell whenM (a.schedule != t.schedule)
  } yield a) exec t
}
```

How should I approach this? Am I on the right track with monad transformers? Anything else I might have missed that already handles my case?

---

**EDIT:**

I got something working like this, it's fine for that use case, but I'd like something that integrates better with State for more complex ones:

```
def reschedule(date: LocalDate): Task => Logger[Task] = { t: Task =>
  for {
    sa <- scheduleL.get(t).point[Logger]
    sb <- changeDue(date)(sa)
    a <- scheduleL.set(t, sb).point[Logger]
    _ <- ("Reschedule: " + a.schedule).point[Vector].tell whenM (a.schedule != t.schedule)
  } yield a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can simplify it further, but that is the best I can get.
To my knowledge you can not use lens in monad transformer directly, but you can convert lens to state, which is close to what you need.

At first lets define our monads.

```
def RWA[R, A] = ReaderWriterState.rwstMonad[Id.Id, R, Vector[String], A]
val RST = RWA[String, Task]
val RLS = RWA[Long, Schedule]


  def changeTitleV1 = for {
    title ← RST.ask // Reader part of transformer getting new title from the environment
    _ ← RST.modify(titleL =>= (_ ⇒ title))  // `=>=` is converting lens to `A => A`
    _ ← RST.tell(Vector(s"I put the value $title")))
  } yield ()


changeTitleV1.run("new title", Task("old title", Schedule(123)))  //(Vector(I put the value new title),(),Task(new title,Schedule(123)))
```

We are passing our new title as the first argument to this `run` function to be able to ask it inside the monad.

As in your example -you want to have a certain condition to write in the log, so you need to get initial state to know if the title has been changed. It is becoming less concise:

```
def changeTitleV2 = for {
    title ← RST.ask
    task0 ← RST.get
    _ ← RST.put(titleL.set(task0, title))
    _ ← RST.whenM(task0.title != title)(RST.tell(Vector(s"I put the value $title")))
  } yield ()
```

Of course you can define the same for changeDue:

```
  def changeDue = for {
    d0 ← RLS.get
    due ← RLS.ask
    _ ← RLS.put(dueL.set(t0, due))
    _ ← RLS.whenM(d0.due != due)(RLS.tell(Vector(s"due changed to $due")))    
  } yield ()
```

That said, I am not so sure, that it is much better, that the solution you came up with.

Comment: As you said it does look similar to what I ended up with, but really I'm starting to discover as I learn more that I probably didn't model the whole thing properly. I had a feeling RWS would show up though, so I'll keep that around as an example, thank you for that.